# HTML Background Chrome not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

i have this html code that plays a video as the full background and it works great for every browser except chrome not sure why can anyone help?

the html code

```
<video poster="" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

the css code

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Where are you finding a "playsinline" attribute? There is no such thing.

Comment: What does not work in chrome exactly? What is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add invert comma `""` in url

```
background: url("polina.jpg") no-repeat;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: that didn't fix it i removed that line it wasn't needed, it runs the background vid.mp4 in same director as the index but still doesn't work after i removed that line

Answer (score 0):

I went and downloaded Vide-0.5.0 which fixed it